# Selectively populating result column

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a query which fetches result from multiple tables:

```
Select 
    TA.C1 as ColumnA, TB.C1 as ColumnB, TC.C1 as ColumnC 
from 
    TableA TA, TableB TB, TableC TC
where 
    --Business Conditions
```

The result fetched is as below:

[image]

Is want the result fetched in a a separate columnD, which has value for each corresponding value of ColumnA e.g:

[image]

PS: If not null , then  value of ColumnB takes Priority over Value of ColumnC (for example `Row 4`)

Can someone suggest what would be the way to achieve this ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Coalesce operator.

```
Select TA.C1 as ColumnA, 
       COALESCE(TB.C1, TC.C1) as ColumnB
       from TableA TA, TableB TB, TableC TC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should try case in select clause.

Code below given should give a rough idea, it is not tested.

```
Select TA.C1 as ColumnA, 
       case 
          when TB.C1 is not NULL THEN TB.C1 
          when TC.C1 is not NULL THEN TC.C1
        end "Column D"
```